# how to use github api token in python for requesting

Tags: api, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, python-requests, github-api

I'm able to obtain Github api token in python using username and password but i'm not able to use that API-Token for requesting any POST/DELETE/PATCH.

How do we use Github API-Tokens for making any request.
For eg, i have API-Token lets say 'hbnajkjanjknjknh23b2jk2kj2jnkl2...'

now for requesting

```
#i'm providing username and API-Token in headers like    
self.header = {'X-Github-Username': self.username,
               'X-Github-API-Token': self.api_token                  
              }
#then requesting(post) to create a gist
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

But i'm always getting `401 error` with `Bad Crediantials` message.

What's the proper way to use API-Tokens without inputting the password

Comment: can't we use something like `requests.post(....,auth=api_token)` instead of `auth=(username,password)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For one, I would recommend using a wrapper for the API. You're asking a lot of questions on here that could be simplified by finding a wrapper whose API you appreciate. There's a list of wrappers written in Python [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#python).

As for your actually answering your question, the GitHub documentation is fairly clear that you need to send the [Authorization header](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication). Your call would actually look like this:

```
self.headers = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % self.api_token}
r = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers)
```

Since it seems like you're using requests and a class, might I be so bold as to make a recommendation? Let's say you're doing something like making a client for the API. You might have a class like so:

```
class GitHub(object):
    def __init__(self, **config_options):
        self.__dict__.update(**config_options)
        self.session = requests.Session()
        if hasattr(self, 'api_token'):
           self.session.headers['Authorization'] = 'token %s' % self.api_token
        elif hasattr(self, 'username') and hasattr(self, 'password'):
           self.session.auth = (self.username, self.password)

    def call_to_the_api(self, *args):
        # do stuff with args
        return self.session.post(url)
```

The Session object will take care of the authentication for you (either by the tokens or username and password combination).

Also, if you end up deciding to use github3.py for your API wrapper needs, there's a tag on here for it.

Comment: using `self.session.headers['Authorization'] = 'token %s' % self.api_token` and not using `auth=(username,password)` inside `requests.post()` is responding back with `{u'message': u'Not Found'}
`

Comment: You don't use `requests.post` with this, you use `self.session.post`.

Comment: It's supposed to be session.get (not post) because the latter responds back with 404

Answer (score 50):

Here's some code that might help you out.

## Examples:

Example 1 (auth):

```
username = 'user'
token = 'token'

login = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=github+api', auth=(username,token))
```

Example 2 (headers):

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + token}

login = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', headers=headers)
print(login.json())
```

Example 3 (delete repo):

```
user = 'username'
repo = 'some_repo' # Delete this repo

headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + token}

login = requests.delete('https://api.github.com/' + 'repos/' + user + '/' + repo, headers=headers)
```

Example 4 (create repo):

```
repo = 'some_repo'
description = 'Created with api'

payload = {'name': repo, 'description': description, 'auto_init': 'true'}

login = requests.post('https://api.github.com/' + 'user/repos', auth=(user,token), data=json.dumps(payload))
```

You might want to take a look at the following docs:

[Requests Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

[Github API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation really helped!

Comment: requests will possibly complain: ssl error, as use https (tls/ssl) without certificate.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt If you get SSL error's on requests, try this:

`CERT_PATH=$(python3 -m certifi)`
`export SSL_CERT_FILE=${CERT_PATH}`
`export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=${CERT_PATH}`

Comment: Its just a hint. Or an insuffiency of your answer, to be a little annoying ;)

Answer (score 5):

I followed the API documentation and tried to set the `Authorization` header in my call to `requests.get()`. However, this always returned a 401 error. So I checked the headers from `Response` object's `request` attribute and found that the `Authorization` header from my request had been rewritten. After a little digging in the source code, I found that when the request calls for HTTP Basic Auth, the `Authorization` header gets rewritten (see [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/9cdf294/requests/auth.py#L95-L97)).

So, the solution was to pass the token in an auth tuple when calling `requests.get()`. For example:

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/notifications', auth=(my_username, my_token))
```

Unfortunately, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626704/1200367) (currently the highest-voted one) won't work, as the method from that answer is precisely what I was using before trying the solution above.

Answer (score 4):

Using the **requests** python library, you need to inform the **Github account API Token** on the request **Headers**.

Example:

```
authorization = f'token {token}'
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    "Authorization" : authorization,
    }
```

Then you can call the resource you wish, example:

```
r = requests.post(
    url=url,
    data=json_data,
    headers=headers
    )
```

You can find more details on the [Github API official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos)

Comment: This does not work. Getting 403 complaining about need to authorize token for the org (while the same token works in command line in Curl and it works with `auth=` as suggested in other answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from github import Github
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
token='.....................'
g=Github(token,per_page=10000)
repos=g.search_repositories(query="q:rgpd")
```